# JavaScript, Async/Await issue chrome extension, executing out of order

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, async-await

I am trying to make a chrome extension for opening lists of urls. I want the option of saving the list in bookmarks under a folder called extension_hook in my bookmarks bar.

The button saveToBookmarks reads a input field and scans folders inside extension_hook inside and if it matches the input it is supposed to get the create a folder with the name of Date(), and then get the id of that folder. something like

```
await createFolder(parent, val)
let id = await getId(parent, val)
```

However I am new to js and don't quite understand the async/await. I've bluffed my way through this far, but now I'm stuck.
It seems like it tries to get the Id before creating the folder even though I am trying to await it.

If you are interested in testing it out, you can create a bookmarks folder called extension_hook and put another folder inside called {NAME}.

```
git clone https://github.com/CatInAHatIsBack/Bookmarks_Opener_ext.git
```

then go to chrome://extensions/ , then
load unpacked
navigate to your download

to recreate my mistake type {NAME} into the input field, then press the button.

```
saveToBookmarks.addEventListener("click", () => {
      let val = projectName.value
      checkForExisting(val)
      console.log("projectName.value : " + val)
    });
```

```
async function checkForExisting(val){
  /**
   *  scan all bookmarks
   *  those who have children are folders
   *  if folder name matches the current extension hook name make a folder inside with date and tome as name
   *  else create folder with specified name 
   */

   let len = hook.children.length
   console.log("hook has x children: " + len)
   let par
   // checks if hook exists
   for (var i =0; i < len; i++) {
    let hookId = hook.id
    if(hook.children[i].title === val){
      console.log("match: " + val)
      // insert txt
      par = i
    }
   }
   // found hook with same name
   // inserts urls into folder with 
   if(par){
    console.log("hook.children[par]: "+ hook.children[par].title)
    // root
    let parents = await urlsAndFolder(hook.children[par])
    console.log("parents returned: "+parents[0])
    await insertUrls(parents[0], parents[1])
   }
   else{
     // not relevant
   }
```

```
async function urlsAndFolder(parent){
  let urls = await txtArea.value.split(URL_LINE_SPLIT_REGEX);
  let time = await getTime() 
  console.log('time is: ' + time)
  await createFolder(parent, time)
  let newCreatedFolder = await getId(parent, time)
  console.log("newCreatedFolder is: "+newCreatedFolder)
  return { newCreatedFolder, urls }
}
```

```
async function insertUrls(parent, urls){
  for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    await createFile(parent, urls[i])
  }  
}
```

```
async function getId(parent, val) {
  let newCreatedFolder
  for (let i = 0; i < parent.children.length; i++) {
    console.log(`parent.children[${i}].title is ${parent.children[i].title} and val is ${val}`)
    if(parent.children[i].title === val){
      newCreatedFolder = parent.children[i]
    }
  } 
  return await newCreatedFolder
}
```

```
async function createFolder(parent,title){
  await chrome.bookmarks.create(
    {'parentId': parent.id, 'title': title}, 
    function(newFolder) {
      console.log("added folder: " + newFolder.title);
    }
  );
}
```

```
async function createFile(parent,url){
  console.log("createFile: "+ parent)
    chrome.bookmarks.create({
      'parentId': parent.id ,
      'url': url,
    });
}
```

output is:

```
newCreatedFolder is: undefined
parents returned: undefined
added folder: 2022-8-18 19:42:45
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at insertUrls (index.js:238:28)
    at checkForExisting (index.js:226:11)
insertUrls @ index.js:238
checkForExisting @ index.js:226
await in checkForExisting (async)
(anonymous) @ index.js:164
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Comment: inside your createFolder function you need to return the result, in order it can be awaited

Comment: just use return chrome.bookmarks.create, no need to use await when you return

Comment: `insertUrls(parent, urls){` takes 2 parameters and it only gets called with 1 - `await insertUrls(id)`. This will mean that the call to `urls.length` will fail because `urls` is undefined.

Comment: @Alopwer did that work for you? I still get it executing out of order.

Comment: @phuzi, I should have been more clear. The else condition is not in question. i just wrote it to remember and didnt change it yet, however it isnt called. they will basically do the same thing i will just have the else condition also create the folder. but first i need to figure out the problem

Comment: this is the out of order issue in question
`let parents = await urlsAndFolder(hook.children[par])`
` console.log("parents returned: "+parents[0])`
`await insertUrls(parents[0], parents[1])`
I would expect this to finish "urlsAndFolder"  and then continue to print 
` console.log("parents returned: "+parents[0])`
`However, it prints, then creates the folder.`
`newCreatedFolder is: undefined`
`parents returned: undefined`
added folder: 2022-8-18 19:42:45

Comment: `urlsAndFolder` returns an object with 2 properties `{ newCreatedFolder, urls }` but you treat the returned value as if it's an array `parents[0]` and `parents[1]` instead of `parents.newCreatedFolder` and `parents.urls`

Comment: `getId` only seems to set `newCreatedFolder` if `parent.children[i].title` and `val` match but in the logged output they don't! `'2022-8-18 19:39:10'` is not `'2022-8-18 19:42:45'`. No idea what the other 6 titles are though!

Comment: @phuzi That is becuase I have prevous entries created this way, they are just earlier entries. The return value isnt really the issue, as the point was more to see when it was chekced. checks 
before the folder is created.
`newCreatedFolder is: undefined`
`parents returned: undefined`
`added folder: 2022-8-18 19:42:45`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can't specify a callback in a `chrome` method if you want to `await` its returned value. Remove the callback in createFolder.
2. Your `createFile` function doesn't wait for the API. Add `await`  before chrome.bookmarks.create.

Comment: `const folder = await createFolder(parent, time)`
`console.log("folder: " + folder)`
`console.log("folder title: " + folder.title)`
`const id = await getId(parent, time)`
Your answer didn't work but it helped get around the problem somewhat. If i do as you say and remove the callback(), and set the return value to folder, it will log out the right folder. However getId() still does not find the folder. I figure it might be an issue with chrome bookmarks not updating {parent}'s children and it runs getId on an outdated reference. But Im no js expert, so i cant say. Thank you though <3